# MemoryError when using gdb's Python extension on Jessie

Tags: debian, python, gdb

In the past, I frequently used the possibility to [attach gdb to a running Python process](http://podoliaka.org/2016/04/10/debugging-cpython-gdb/) and use the `py-*` extensions for debugging. However, since Debian Jessie, this does not work anymore and throws a `MemoryError` instead.

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a Vagrant machine with `debian/jessie64` box
- In the box `sudo apt-get install gdb python-dbg`
- Create a test file `echo "raw_input()" > test.py"` and run `python test.py`
- Attach with gdb `gdb -p <processe's PID>`
- Try `py-bt` or any other `py-*` command

Result is:

```
(gdb) py-bt
Python Exception <class 'gdb.MemoryError'> Cannot access memory at address 0x12: 
Error occurred in Python command: Cannot access memory at address 0x12
```

... when using `debian/wheezy64` as base box:

```
#10 Frame 0xf2faf0, for file test.py, line 1, in <module> ()
    raw_input()
```

Anyone encountered and solved this issue?